# Set Tickpositions

Tags: asp.net, dotnethighcharts

I work for the first time with the Dotnet.Highcharts framework in Visual Basic and I need your help. 
I want to set the tickpositions, but I do not know how.

```
code snippet:
.SetYAxis(New YAxis With {.GridLineWidth = 0, _
         .Title = New YAxisTitle With {.Text = "test text"}, _
         .Min = 1, _
         .Max = 3, _
         .TickPositions = ??? })
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TickPositions` property of the [`YAxis`](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DotNet.Highcharts/DotNet.Highcharts/Options/YAxis.cs) class is of type [`Number?()`](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DotNet.Highcharts/DotNet.Highcharts/Helpers/Number.cs) which is an array of a specific Highcharts type to represent numbers

There are implicit conversion operators in the code for `Number` from `int`, `double`, and nullable `int`s and `double`s, as well as constructors, so defining an array of them can be as easy as:

```
Dim tickPositions as Number?() = New Number?() {1, 2.5, new Number(123)}
```

or in your inline code:

```
.TickPositions = New Number?() {1, 2.5, new Number(123)} })
```

Comment: that's it. I was wondering about "number?" and had only written "number", instead of number?